# Could someone explain me w.r.t. coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates

Could someone please explain me what are w.r.t. coordinates? or at least direct me to a place that explains what they are? I've being searching for two days or so and all that I found is tutorials on how are they used but not what they actually are or even what wrt stand for.

These tutorials take the assumption I already know what they are which is stressful because I've never heard of them.

I'm working in as3 trying to do some parametric surfaces using pixel particles and I understand these are kind of useful while moving the particles around.

This is the relevant function where they are used as u,v and w, where p is a single particle that also contains xyz values that are not being modified.

```
function onEnter(evt:Event):void {

dphi = 0.015*Math.cos(getTimer()*0.000132);
dtheta = 0.017*Math.cos(getTimer()*0.000244);

phi = (phi + dphi) % pi2;
theta = (theta + dtheta) % pi2;

cost = Math.cos(theta);
sint = Math.sin(theta);
cosp = Math.cos(phi);
sinp = Math.sin(phi);

//We calculate some of the rotation matrix entries here for increased efficiency:
M11 = cost*sinp;
M12 = sint*sinp;
M31 = -cost*cosp;
M32 = -sint*cosp;

p = firstParticle;

//////// redrawing ////////
displayBitmapData.lock();

//apply filters pre-update
displayBitmapData.colorTransform(displayBitmapData.rect,darken);
displayBitmapData.applyFilter(displayBitmapData, displayBitmapData.rect, origin, blur);

p = firstParticle;
do {

    //Calculate rotated coordinates     
    p.u = M11*p.x + M12*p.y + cosp*p.z;
    p.v = -sint*p.x + cost*p.y;
    p.w = M31*p.x + M32*p.y + sinp*p.z;

    //Calculate viewplane projection coordinates
    m = fLen/(fLen - p.u);
    p.projX = p.v*m + projCenterX;
    p.projY = p.w*m + projCenterY;

    if ((p.projX > displayWidth)||(p.projX<0)||(p.projY<0)||(p.projY>displayHeight)||(p.u>uMax)) {
        p.onScreen = false;
    }
    else {
        p.onScreen = true;
    }

    if (p.onScreen) {

            //we read the color in the position where we will place another particle:
            readColor = displayBitmapData.getPixel(p.projX, p.projY);

            //we take the blue value of this color to represent the current brightness in this position,
            //then we increase this brightness by levelInc.
            level = (readColor & 0xFF)+levelInc;

            //we make sure that 'level' stays smaller than 255:
            level = (level > 255) ? 255 : level;

            /*
            We create light blue pixels quickly with a trick:
            the red component will be zero, the blue component will be 'level', and
            the green component will be 50% of the blue value.  We divide 'level' in
            half using a fast technique: a bit-shift operation of shifting down by one bit
            accomplishes the same thing as dividing by two (for an integer output).
            */
            //dColor = ((level>>1) << 8) | level;

            dColor = (level << 16) | (level << 8) | level;

            displayBitmapData.setPixel(p.projX, p.projY, dColor);               
    }

    p = p.next;

} while (p != null)

displayBitmapData.unlock();
```

}

This is the example I'm using http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/light/
I kinda understand how are they used but I don't get why.

Thanks in advance.

PD: kind of surprised there is not even a tag related to it.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your case, but usually w.r.t stands for: with respect to. Can you give an example sentence that is using it?

Comment: "I want to get the values of picked point wrt to SA1 origin and NOT MA." It kind of makes sense in certain contexts but wrt is being used in coding as the xyz coordinates, I'll put an example.

Comment: Are you asking about u, v, and w?

Comment: yes, they are referred in the comments in the particle class as wrt coordinates and by searching that is how many people call them

Comment: I see, `//coords WRT viewpoint axes`

I am pretty sure they mean with respect to.
What they are doing is converting the particle's world space coordinate to a viewing space coordinate. The origin of the world space is different from the origin of the view space (camera).

Comment: That makes sense, so they are only used to store the coordinates of the camera in relation to the particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that Particle3D.as class linked, they have:

```
//coords WRT viewpoint axes
public var u:Number;
public var v:Number;
public var w:Number;
```

From the code example you posted to the question it becomes clear that `coords WRT viewpoint axes` means `coordinates with respect to viewpoint axes`, since the code is doing exactly that .

What they are doing is a **Camera (or Viewing)** Transformation, where the Particle's world coordinates (x,y,z) is transformed from the world coordinate system to coordinates in the camera (or view) coordinate system (u,v,w).

(x,y,z) are the coordinates of the **particle** in the **world** coordinate system

(u,v,w) are the coordinates of the **particle** in the **camera** coordinate system

For example, the world coordinate system might have an origin at (0,0,0) with the camera positioned at something like (5,3,6) with an lookat vector of (1,0,0) and up vector of (0,1,0).

Comment: Thank you, this really clear things out, I was getting really confused as to why they where using it